# JavaScriptでmetaタグ内のlink要素の一部を書き換えたい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptを使ってページロード時にmetaタグ内ののソースコードを書き換えたいです。

`<link>` タグを取得して書き換えるところまではできたのですが、

- `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="/css/style.css" />`

のように読み込むものが複数ある場合に、rel="stylesheet" の href だけを書き換えたい場合、
以下のコードをどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allParas = document.head.getElementsByTagName('link');
    console.log(allParas);
    var root = 'http://test.com';
    let len = allParas.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if ( allParas.item(i).href.match(/http/) == null) {
        allParas.item(i).href = root + allParas.item(i).href;
        allParas.item(i).href = allParas.item(i).href.replace( /file\/\//g , "" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.head.getElementsByTagName('link')` を `document.head.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')` に変更すればご希望どおりになるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、期待通りの書き換えになりました。ご親切にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

jQueryが使えるならば`$("link[rel='stylesheet']")`のようにセレクタで表現できます。
[jQuery日本語リファレンス](http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/selectors/%5Battribute+value%5D/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="./css/style.css" />
<title>サンプル</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    let para = $("link[rel='stylesheet']")[0];
    console.log(para.href);
    para.href = "./css/style2.css" ;
    console.log(para.href);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、ご教授いだたいた方法で期待通りの結果になりました。
Jqueryも使える環境ですので試してみます。